# How i can rename particular files from cgh_xxx1 to xx1in in unix?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a directory /home/logs which contain multiple subdirectories .

Each subdirectories has multiple files which start with string cgh_filename.txt . I want to rename all these file like this filename.txt.. basically wanted to remove this "cgh_" from each file to each directory..

Comment: Input cgh_xx1.txt , cgh_ty1.txt , cgh_uio.txt OUTPUT should be xx1.txt ,  ty1.txt , uio.txt

Answer (score 0):

Not really tested, but something like this could work:

```
find . -name cgh_* | xargs -I{} -n1 sh -c 'file="$(basename $1)"; dir="$(dirname $1)" ; mv "${dir}/${file}" "${dir}/${file#cgh_}"' -- {}
```